# How to play HLS stream when segments' names need to add access signature

Tags: azure, signature, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm developing a media player APP playing HLS streams. Our video segments are stored on Azure Blob storage. Now it's ok to play HLS links like

https://myazure.blob.com/folder/info.m3u8

But the problem is that we want to add Shared Access Signature (SAS) for all video containers and their segments to protect them from public accessing, so when accessing segments, the https links need to include the SAS. For example, when playing a segment named "out0000.mp4", the link should be like

https://myazure.blob.com/folder/out0000.mp4?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&si=SignaturePublicb0&sig=pUKa1i%2F9GdjAj1VhLe%2FVU5NBNig%3D

It's ok to access info.m3u8 by adding SAS like,

https://myazure.blob.com/folder/info.m3u8?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&si=SignaturePublicb0&sig=pUKa1i%2F9GdjAj1VhLe%2FVU5NBNig%3D

But in info.m3u8, the format is like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXTINF:5.100000,
out0000.mp4
#EXTINF:5.000000,
out0001.mp4
#EXTINF:5.000000,
out0002.mp4
#EXTINF:5.000000,
out0003.mp4
...
```

without SAS following the names of segments. So the player cannot access those segments and play.

And I don't want to change info.m3u8 to include SAS for each segment. Is there a way to solve this problem? Any suggestions? Thanks.

By the way, I'm using MediaPlayer in Android and AVPlayer in iOS.

Comment: You want to change the m3u8, without changing the m3u8. No, thats not possible. Maybe make a m3u8 generation server?

Comment: It's much easier to do a proxy like @szatmary suggested. This way you don't need to implement a custom solution for each platform / new player and it's easier to maintain / extend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @aergistal But could it generate new m3u8 on-the-fly? Because I also need to play live shows, which means m3u8 will keep changing

Comment: @szatmary I hope there are tools or other player frameworks that can modify segment name on-the-fly while processing m3u8. Actually I did achieve this by hls.js and xhrSetup on html5 player.

Comment: @Harrison live playlists are reloaded periodically, just intercept each request.

Comment: @aergistal Yes, sounds good. By that way, I could generate new m3u8. But could you explain more in an Answer about how to "intercept each request"? Or some references? Will really appreciate that, thanks.

Comment: @Harrison - curious if you ever figured out a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the HLS principle
where you typically have a master m3u8 that link to
a manifest.m3u8 for each quality version of the video.
Where each such manifest.m3u8 list video segments, each with a .ts (transport stream) extension.
There may exist further divisions such as chapters each represented by a manifest and quality version folders under each chapter.
None of the .ts segments are meant to be accessed individually by users,
only from m3u8 indexes.
There may be further arrangements with folders per language, etc.
So by placing each of the manifests and subfolders with segments
in a folder accessible only by logged in viewers with the proper access right to the manifests folder, then only those users will be able to
access the content. See details of HLS: https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/2017/08/hls-streaming-hls-encryption-secure-hls-drm/
Amazon Cloudfront supports a solution with Signed Cookies:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html